# How to match and join results between two resolvers in one graphql query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I have two resolver.

The one is Company resolve that return the company details like id, name and list of documents ids, like this example:

```
{
  "data": {
    "companyOne": {
      "name": "twitter",
      "documents": [
            "5c6c0213f0fa854bd7d4a38c",
            "5c6c02948e0001a16529a1a1",
            "5c6c02ee7e76c12075850119",
            "5c6ef2ddd16e19889ffaffd0",
            "5c72fb723ebf7b2881679ced",
            "5c753d1c2e080fa4a2f86c87",
            ...
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And the another resolver gets me all the details of documents like this example:

```
{
  "data": {
    "documentsMany": [{
      "name": "doc1",
      "_id": 5c6c0213f0fa854bd7d4a38c,
     }, {
      "name": "doc2",
      "_id": 5c6c02948e0001a16529a1a1,
     },
     ...
    ]
  }
}
```

How to match every `data.companyOne.documents[id]` to `data.documentsMany[..]._id`? in the query level? is it possible to do this graphql?

The expect results should be when I run the companyOne query (without change the code - just in the query level) it's should return with documents as object instead of array of string ids.

maybe something like?

```
query {
  companyOne {
   name, 
   documents on documentsMany where _id is ___???
  }
}
```